# Get the last inserted document in mongodb java

Tags: java, mongodb

I need to get the last inserted client so i can create an secuencial id, i tried a @Query annotation with the follow path but it doesnt run the app.

````
public interface ClienteRepository extends MongoRepository<Cliente, String> {

    @Query("[{ $sort: ({ _id: -1}).limit:(1)}]")
    Cliente findLastCliente();

}```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clienteRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
[{ $sort: ({ _id: -1}).limit:(1)}]
````

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 3 ways

1: Directly use this. Spring will automatically create desired query for you

```
Cliente findTopByOrderByIdDesc();
```

2: You can use Pageable and get only 1 record.

```
@Query(sort = "{ _id : -1 }");
Page<Cliente> findByMethod(Pageable pageable);

// Inside service
Page fooPage = FooRepository.findByMethod('John', new PageRequest(0,1));
```

3: Custom Query

```
Query query = new Query();
query.limit(1);
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "_id"));

mongoOperation.find(query, Cliente.class);
```

I would prefer the 1st option

By the way issue you are getting is because this `@Query("[{ $sort: ({ _id: -1}).limit:(1)}]")` is not in correct JSON format which can be translate to Mongo Query.

Comment: how would you instance that query to be reusable in others places, i mean, i need to  use the query in others service as well and rewritten it again seems wrong

Comment: Which way you are talking about out of 3.  You can use first one, you need to add that in ClienteRepository and it will be available for other services to use.

Comment: i have another question, i have a colecctions with 3 different product classes, how i filter for the last one from an specific class?

i tried with query.with(new Criteria(where(product).is(ProductEnum.PIZZA) but diddnt work